# How to specify disk space in AWS task definitions?

Tags: amazon-web-services

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

I see I can specify CPU and memory, but what about disk space? What should I do if I want a docker running on a machine with 200GB disk space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For instance based ECS,  the container is run on a base AMI, which is customized by AWS for running ECS docker containers. The instance itself has 2 volumes, a boot volume, and a docker volume. Run `lsblk` on the instance, and you will see these volumes.

By default, the docker volume is set to 16gb in the base AMI
volume configuration. You can set the desired size of this volume as you would an EC2 instance, according to your launch configuration in the autoscaling group.

For more information, see Amazon Elastic Container Service Storage Configuration:

> >
>   By default, the Amazon ECS-optimized Amazon Linux AMI ships with 30 GiB of total storage. You can modify this value at launch time to increase or decrease the available storage on your container instance. This storage is used for the operating system and for Docker images and metadata. The sections below describe the storage configuration of the Amazon ECS-optimized Amazon Linux AMI, based on the AMI version.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-ami-storage-config.html